# Test for missing region element in a marionette layout view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

Is there an elegant way in Marionette to test if a region's (el)ement exists in the DOM after the view is rendered? Preferably without rewriting the region selector and using jQuery to search the DOM.

For example - this layout view:

```
var view = new Marionette.LayoutView({

 regions : {
  'header' : '.header',
  'footer' : '.footer'
 },

 onRender : function() {
  if ( /* test for the existance of 'header' in the dom */ ) {
   // do something
  }
 }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elegant? No. But Marionette's `view.getRegion()._ensureElement()` returns true when the element exists and will throw an error if the element does not exist.  So you could try...

```
 onRender : function() {
   try {
     view.getRegion("header")._ensureElement()
     // element exists
   } catch {
     //element does not exist
   }
```

The [annotated marionette source](http://marionettejs.com/annotated-src/backbone.marionette.html#section-165) also suggests that there is a `allowMissingEl` option that you could set to have `_ensureElement()` return false when the element does not exist, but this might have negative repercussions for the rest of your project, and could potentially make debugging more difficult.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the source, it looks like Morslamina's answer is correct - however we can extend Marionette's region class and implement the testing behavior ourselves. For example:

```
var BaseRegion = Marionette.Region.extend({

    // tests if the element exists for this region or not
    hasEl : function() {
        if ( _.isUndefined(this.getEl(this.el)[0]) ) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

and then in the layout view go

```
var Layout = Marionette.Layout.extend({

    regionClass: BaseRegion,

    regions : {
        'header' : '.header',
        'footer' : '.footer'
    },

    onRender : function() {
        if ( this.getRegion('header').hasEl() ) {
            // do something, e.g. show the region
        }
    }

});
```